# Azure Service Bus client: Best way to wait for server response?

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, asynchronous, azureservicebus

I have a web service that needs to send a request on Azure Service Bus and wait for the response. The web service must operate synchronous as seen from the web service client, that is:

```
public Response WebServiceMethod(Request)
{
   senderQueueClient.Send(Request);

   // wait for response from receiverQueueClient.OnMessage(..)
   // and return to web service client

   return response;
}
```

I have searched the topic but came up short for this specific case, where there could be lots of concurrent web service calls, and where I know that the response in "receiverQueueClient.OnMessage(..)" is delivered in different thread.

How to solve this correct? ManualResetEvent or perhaps using the new await/async in .NET4.5?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out PushoverQ on github.  Its an async client for ASB.

Comment: @TheGreatCO: Thanks but what I'm after is how best to use ASB as if it were a synchronous req/res model. Can't see PushoverQ does this anywhere?